# PHP PDO UPDATE statement with subquery

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, subquery

I'm trying to create a query using PDO, where the query includes a subquery. The code isn't working. Using the workbench, I can do the query and it does perform.

I feel like there is nuance here when it comes to deriving a table while using PDO.

```
    $turn = 1;
    $phase = -1;
    $status = "waiting";
    $gameid = 1;

        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare("
            UPDATE playerstatus 
            SET 
                turn = :turn,
                phase = :phase,
                status = :status,
                value = value + (SELECT reinforce FROM games where id = :gameid)
            WHERE
                gameid = :gameid                
        ");

        $stmt->bindParam(":turn", $turn);
        $stmt->bindParam(":phase", $phase);
        $stmt->bindParam(":status", $status);
        $stmt->bindParam(":gameid", $gameid);

        $stmt->execute();
```

I tried a multitude of adjustments, it simply fails upon executing.

EDIT error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Comment: "it simply fails upon executing". It doesn't simply fails. It throws an error, post us the error!

Comment: chill.
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Comment: The answer is on the error. You have 5 parameters on your query, but you only bound 4 parameters (you must repeat the `:gameid`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A known (but not well documented) limitation with PDO named placholders: the same bind placeholder can't be used more than one time in a statement.  Workaround is to use distinct bind placeholder names.

(This limitation in PDO may have been addressed in a later versions(?). I think the root cause is that "behind the scenes", PDO is replacing the named placeholders with positional notation question marks.  This problem is not restricted to just UPDATE statements, this same problem plagues all PDO SQL statements using named placeholders.)

---

Also, not related to the problem, I recommend using `bindValue` in place of `bindParam`.

Change the bind placeholder name to be distinct/unique. Shown here, changing one of the occurrences of `:gameid` to `:gameid2`

```
           value = value + (SELECT reinforce FROM games where id = :gameid)
        WHERE
            gameid = :gameid2
                            ^
```

And we need to supply a value for each bind placeholder. Which means we need to add another line.  With `bindValue`, we can reference the same variable without needing make a copy of it.

```
    $stmt->bindValue(":gameid", $gameid);
    $stmt->bindValue(":gameid2", $gameid);
                             ^
```

Comment: well, that did solve my issue. I was pretty sure i could use 2 instances of :gameid tied to a single Param.
Your logic is sound however, and i understand the problem. Much appreciated.

Comment: It's not unusual to expect that we could reference the same named placeholder multiple places within a statement. (We can do it with other databases/drivers, for example Perl DBD::Oracle.) When I encountered the problem, I couldn't find documentation about the PDO limitation.  All I found was that the PDO documentation doesn't show any examples of reusing the same placeholder. So, it's sorta documented?